# Divide two numbers, then apply a custom rounding rule

Tags: c#, floating-point

If the fractional part of the number is greater than 0.6, round up; if less, round down.
I need feedback about my code.

```
public static double DivisionMethod(double a, double b)
{
      double div = a / b;
      double temp = Math.Floor(div);
      double fractional = div - temp;

      if (fractional > 0.6)
      {
          return Math.Ceiling(div);
      }
      else
      {
          return Math.Floor(div);
      }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean "if less *or equal* - round down"?

Comment: Also, by round down, do you mean towards zero or towards negative infinity? Would -2.5 round to -2 (towards zero) or -3 (towards negative infinity)?

Comment: @dcastro fractional is within `[-1, 1[`. But your question is still valid for the negative values.

Comment: You might enjoy this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921180/how-can-i-ensure-that-a-division-of-integers-is-always-rounded-up/926806#926806 The lesson here is that even smart people can get division completely wrong, over and over again.  You are very wise to be careful about your code and get it reviewed.

Comment: @dcastro When working on double instead of decimal, that distinction has no practical relevance since doubles can't represent 0.6 in the first place.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Can't they? `double d = 1.2d/2d;
d == 0.6` [evaluates as true](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3DJ257).

Comment: @dcastro The double constant `0.6` isn't 0.6 in the mathematical sense anymore. That your equation evaluates to `true` is merely luck. There are similar looking equations (such as `double d = 1.2d/3d; d == 0.4` that won't do so. I'm not even sure if it your example will work reproducibly across different implementations an hardware.

Comment: @CodesInChaos True, it might not work on other hardware, it also might not work for other similar divisions (e.g., `1.8/3`). But my point was, it *might* be 0.6.

Comment: @dcastro My original claim was that 0.6 cannot be represented exactly as double, which is doubtlessly true. So deciding what should happen with 0.6 is meaningless. If that question is important, using double was already a bug.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Maybe I'm misunderstanding something... how can `d` equal `0.6`, if 0.6 cannot be represented exactly as double? The way I see it, `d` was able to represent 0.6 exactly.

Comment: @dcastro If both sides round to the same representable value, the equation will evaluate to true, even if neither side is 0.6 precisely. Floating point rounding rules are subtle, even when strictly following IEEE 754 semantics, and C# doesn't even guarantee that.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I see what you mean now. You're right, it doesn't make sense to handle equality.

Comment: @dcastro: Pulling up [`MiscUtil.Conversion.DoubleConverter.ToExactString`](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/), `0.6d` is represented as `0.59999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375` (as is `1.2d/2d`).  Mentally replace all instances of 0.6 with that horrifying number.  During output, C# often prints out `0.6` (because it chops of the last few digits for display).

Comment: This is kind of a trivial point, but there doesn't seem to be any reason for this to be *both* a division and a custom rounding function; it could just be a custom rounding function that takes one floating point value as input.

Answer (score 20):

`DivisionMethod` is a pretty vague/poor name for your method; any method with the word "method" in it should raise a "bad name" flag!

Also, hard-coding the threshold into the function takes away flexibility. Perhaps I'd consider an optional parameter, like this:

```
public static double RoundedDivision(double a, double b, double threshold = 0.6)
```

Okay, not sure `RoundedDivision` is a *much* better name... *naming is hard!*. This is where XML comments can help:

```
/// <summary>
/// Divides <c>a</c> by <c>b</c> and round up if quotient is
/// greater than <c>threshold</c>, round down if it's less. 
/// </summary>
public static double RoundedDivision(double a, double b, double threshold = 0.6)
```

It's probably best to call a cat, a cat: `a` is the `dividend` and `b` is the `divisor`, so the method would be clearer with a signature like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Divides <c>dividend</c> by <c>divisor</c> and round up if quotient is
/// greater than <c>threshold</c>, round down if it's less. 
/// </summary>
public static double RoundedDivision(double dividend, double divisor, double threshold = 0.6)
```

As was mentioned in the comments, there's an ambiguity issue with the threshold: what happens if the quotient is *exactly* equal to the threshold?

Answer (score 14):

First, you're calculating `Math.Floor(div)` twice. You have already stored it in temp (and why not give it a more clear name, like floor).

Second, you don't need the fractional variable:

```
if (div - floor > 0.6) etc.
```

Third, `Math.Ceiling` in this case is equal to floor + 1;

The rest is a matter of personal style. Some people would remove the braces and some would use a ternary operator instead of if/else, like this:

```
public static double DivisionMethod(double a, double b)
{
  double div = a / b;
  double floor = Math.Floor(div);
  return div - floor > 0.6 ? floor + 1 : floor;
}
```

Comment: `Math.Ceiling(...)` is equal to `floor+1`... as long as `div` is not an integer. If it is an integer, they're the same.

Comment: @Snowbody If `div` is an integer, `div - floor` is `0`, so `floor + 1` is never reached.

Comment: @Snowbody You're right of course. What I meant was the return value. If floor > 0.6 then you don't have to calculate Math.Ceiling

Comment: @dennis_e Rereading the post it seems that you are saying that only in that specific case, you can guarantee `Math.Ceiling() == floor+1` but I didn't pick that up the first time.

Answer (score 8):

The other answers are good. I would add to them:

- Show us your test cases and their results; we can criticize them as well and show you what test cases you should be using.
- Do you find it a little bit strange that `DivisionMethod(10, 7)` is `1` but `DivisionMethod(-10, 7)` is `-2` ? I would expect that changing the *sign* of an operand should change the *sign* of the output, not the *sign and magnitude* of the output. This is not a question about the *action* of the code, but rather *whether the method is poorly specified to begin with*. Any method that deals with division and rounding **I expect the specification to say very clearly what to do in the case of negative numbers**.
- Note that 0.6 cannot be represented *exactly* by a double; doubles are fractions where the denominator is a power of two, and three-fifths cannot be made to have a power of two on the bottom. If your intention is to represent *exactly* fractions which have a power of ten on the bottom, you need to use `decimal`, not `double`.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static double DivisionMethod(double dividend, double divisor)
{
  double div = dividend / divisor;
  double floor = Math.Floor(div);
  return div - floor <= 0.6 ? floor : floor+ 1;
}
```

There is more probability that `div - Math.Floor(div)` is smaller then and equal to `0.6`.  so I think it's a good practise to use

```
div - floor <= 0.6 ? floor : floor + 1;
```

instead of

```
div - floor > 0.6 ? floor + 1 : floor;
```

by this reduced the probability of adding 1 to `floor`.

Comment: especially since the second way of writing it is **wrong** if `div` happens to be an integer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want 0.6 -> 0.0 then `return Math.Ceiling(x/y - 0.6 )`

If you want 0.6 -> 1.0 then `return Math.Floor(x/y + 1 - 0.6)`

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account previous suggestions, I propose the following, which:

- Provides better names
- Handles divide by zero
- Handles negative outcomes

```
public static double CustomDivision(double dividend, double divisor, double threshold = 0.6)
{
    // Start with divisor in case it's zero
    double answer = divisor;

    // Avoid divide by zero error
    if (!divisor.Equals(0.0))
    {
        // Perform calculations
        answer = dividend / divisor;
        double floor = Math.Floor(answer);
        double ceiling = Math.Ceiling(answer);
        bool isPositive = answer < 0 ? false : true;
        double remainder = answer - (isPositive ? floor : ceiling);

        // Which way to round depends on sign and remainder
        bool roundUp = isPositive ? 
            (Math.Abs(remainder) > threshold ? true : false) : 
            (Math.Abs(remainder) > threshold ? false : true);

        // Now we know which way to round
        answer = roundUp ? ceiling : floor;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for a review here ?

Comment: This is a place to review code, not post your own code. What comments do you have about the OP's code?

Comment: OP's code didn't handle negatives and didn't check for divide by zero.

Comment: @ms.spock: You should also mention that in the answer, so that it's clear that you're pointing out a flaw in the code.  Otherwise, this may be subject to deletion.